# How do I prevent Application Launcher pop-up when Win-key is pressed in KDE?

Tags: shortcut-keys, kde, keyboard-layout

I have KDE. I want to use the left <kbd>Win</kbd> key for switching keyboard layout.
However after the setup it works but it also causes the Application Launcher pop-up.
How can I disable this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The accepted answer here helped me:

https://superuser.com/questions/1156130/kde-disable-super-l-windows-key-key-shortcut-as-menu-luncher

In short:

Put

```
[ModifierOnlyShortcuts]
Meta=
```

in **~/.config/kwinrc**

Logout and login. After that the Windows key only switched the keyboard layout. The Application Launcher didn't pop-up.

Comment: `kwriteconfig5 --file ~/.config/kwinrc --group ModifierOnlyShortcuts --key Meta ""
qdbus org.kde.KWin /KWin reconfigure`

Comment: From https://userbase.kde.org/Plasma/Tips#Windows.2FMeta_Key

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like you need Gnome Tweaks to solve your problem, the solution is to swap it for the right one with this option:

[image: disable or swap to use the other windows/super key using gnome-tweaks]

Look for `gnome-tweaks` in the `Ubuntu Software` centre/store:

[image: Gnome-Tweaks in the software centre]

Then install it as I have above. Once there do the following:

1. Open `gnome-tweaks`, either in the terminal or looking for `Tweaks` in the dash.
2. Change to the `Keyboard & Mouse` tab on the left-hand navigation.
3. Then look for `Overview Shortcut` on the right-hand side and click on `Right Super`.
4. Done.

The added bonus is if you don't need this menu, and you don't have a right Super (windows) key - then this just disables that functionality altogether. Unless you get a Bluetooth keyboard or plug in a different one that does, then it will serve the menu if you press the rightmost one.

Hope this helps you out.

Comment: Cannot find "Overview Shortcut"

Comment: Looks like the OP edited their post to say they have KDE.

Comment: @MichaelHampton yeah, OP did. They didn't mention that they weren't using the default Ubuntu install. I presume they're using Kubuntu.